# skimage regionprops does not segmentate character when background is coulored behind the character

Tags: python, ocr, scikit-image

i'm trying to make an ANPLR system, but my plate examples(and a lot of plates in my country) has a kind of background behind the plate characters, here is an example,

[image: original plate]

after making a threshold_otsu filter

```
threshold_value = threshold_otsu(gray_car_image)
binary_car_image = gray_car_image > threshold_value
```

and regionprops

```
for i in range(len(cca2.plate_like_objects)):
    license_plate = np.invert(cca2.plate_like_objects[i])
    labelled_plate = measure.label(license_plate, background=0, connectivity=1)
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1)
    ax1.imshow(license_plate, cmap="gray")
    character_dimensions = (k1, k2, k3, k4)
    min_height, max_height, min_width, max_width = character_dimensions
    characters = []
    counter=0
    column_list = []
    for regions in regionprops(labelled_plate):
        y0, x0, y1, x1 = regions.bbox[0] ,regions.bbox[1],regions.bbox[3], regions.bbox[4]
        region_height = y1 - y0
        region_width = x1 - x0
        if region_height > min_height and region_height < max_height and region_width > min_width and region_width < max_width:
            roi = license_plate[y0:y1, x0:x1]
            rect_border = patches.Rectangle((x0, y1), x1 - x0, y1 - y0, edgecolor="red",                  linewidth=2, fill=False)
            ax1.add_patch(rect_border)
            resized_char = resize(roi, (40, 80))
            characters.append(resized_char)
            column_list.append(x0)
    plt.show()
```

i get

[image]

now here is my question, is there a filter or some method in order to make this character recognizable by regionprops? another options or suggestions?

edit: i had made some progress here, not much but some, if i apply

```
threshold_value = threshold_niblack(gray_car_image)
binary_car_image = gray_car_image > threshold_value
```

instead of threshold_otsu

i get another character recognized, but i still have the "2" out of the segmentation, any help would be amazing, here is the plate

[image: another char]

Comment: Have you tried morphological operations like opening, closing, erode, dilation.
Also, you could run a gaussian median filter as first step to smooth things out.
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html

Comment: Those characters are waaaay darker than the background. I would try a different thresholding method than Otsu. there is also `skimage.filters.try_all_threshold` to check for the best one.

Comment: at the end i solved this problem using some dilate and blur before the threshold,